# Shopping card value of organic channels becomes lower. Why?

Tags: seo, ecommerce, shopping-cart

I monitor lowering of the shopping card value of organic channel. The shopping card value doesnt drop, but becomes lower, minus 25% while last three months. Other channels (paid, affiliate, newsletter) are not affected. The vertical is online print.
What could you imagine as causes?